# how to compute the resource allocated(Allocated Memory) for spark application?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

as we know when submit a spark application, the cluster will allocate resource to run it, but how to calculate the total allocated memory, for example, with the default config, required for the application?

[image: application history for hadoop yarn cluster]

Answer (score 2):

The total allocated memory for the spark job can be given by the formula

```
Total Memory =  memory required by the driver + the memory used by executors * number of executors
```

When you submit the spark job you generally specify driver_memory, num_executors and executor_memory.

If you are not specifying that spark put the defaut values. The default values for spark can be found in conf/spark-defaults.conf Check [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#loading-default-configurations)